# Right-continuity of the expectation of a supermartingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

I start with a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},(\mathcal{F}_t),P)$. I assume that the filtration is right-continuous. On this probability space I define a supermartingale $M$. Now suppose that I can find another process $N$ such that $N$ is a cadlag modification of $M$. Hence it is also a supermartingale. Does this imply that the mapping $t\mapsto E[M_t]$ is right-continuous?

I reasoned as follows. I consider an arbitrary sequence of rationals $t_n \downarrow t$ for some $t\geq 0$. I need to show $\lim_{t_n \downarrow t} E[M_{t_n}-M_t] = 0$.

$$\lim_{t_n \downarrow t} E[M_{t_n}-M_t] = \lim_{t_n \downarrow t} E[M_{t_n}-M_t+N_t-N_t] $$
It feels very tempting to say $\lim_{t_n \downarrow t} E[M_{t_n}-N_t] = 0$ because of something like Levy-Doob downward convergence theorem. Because the
$$\lim_{t_n \downarrow t} E[M_{t_n}-M_t] = \lim_{t_n \downarrow t} E[-M_t+N_t] = 0 $$
by the fact that $M$ and $N$ are modifications.

Can someone tell me whether what I am saying is sensible and if possible, what I would need to do to make the argument rigorous?

Answer (score 2):

Because $N$ is a modification of $M$, $E(M_t)=E(N_t)$ for all $t\ge 0$. What do you know about the right continuity of $t\mapsto E(N_t)$?

Comment: I guess that that mapping is right-continuous. But how do you prove that? $N$ being cadlag doesn't immediately lead to this result. There is a step in between, which I think is filled by Levy-Doob downward convergence. If you know an easier way, I am all ears :)

Comment: You are correct, and I have no easier way; by the backward (super-)martingale convergence theorem, $N_s$ converges a.s. and in $L^1$ to $N_t$ as $s$ decreases to $t$. In particular, $E[N_s]$ converges to $E[N_t]$.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather go for this decomposition $M_{t_n}-M_t=M_{t_n}-N_{t_n}+N_{t_n}-N_t+N_t-M_t$. Then as $E[M_{t_n}-N_{t_n}]$ and $E[M_{t}-N_{t}]$ are null by the modification hypothesis, we only have to prove the result for the process $N$, i.e. :

$lim_{n\to\infty} E[N_{t_n}-N_t]=0$

But $N_t$ is a super martingale so that $N_t\geq E[N_{t_n}|\mathcal{F}_t]$ and then $E[N_t]\geq E[N_{t_n}]=E[E[N_{t_n}|\mathcal{F}_t]]$, also note that $N_{t_n}\to N_t$ as $N$ is càd implies that $E[N_{t_n}|\mathcal{F}_t]\to N_t$ almost surely, so we we can apply monotone convergence theorem to $E[N_{t_n}|\mathcal{F}_t]$ to get the result.

best regards.

Comment: I actually went for the suggestion of John Dawkins and I applied the Levy Doob downward theorem. I understand your method as well. I hope I didn't mess something up by oversimplifying the problem. The subtleties in these things go above my head sometimes.

Comment: @Calculon As a matter of fact the comment of "John Dawkins", where he suggests the use of the backward super martingale convergence theorem is the same approach as mine unless mistaken. Best regards.

Comment: Does your claim that $E[N_{t_n}|\mathcal F_t]\to N_t$ almost surely given the cadlag assumption follow from some form of monotone convergence theorem too?

Comment: Yes using a conditional form of it (proved by multiplying by the indicator of any set in $\mathcal{F}_t$ and then apply the "classical" monotone convergence), so you can see it this way NB:  (conditional) monotony is coming form the fact that $E[N_{t_n}|\mathcal F_t] $ is decreasing in $n$ from super martingale property. regards